# Android - OpenGL Image doesnt rotate (almost completed)

Tags: android, opengl-es

I was following a OpenGL tutorial (https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/touch.html#angle) and I did everything right I think. **My problem is that the triangle doesnt rotate on the display.** I tried to debug and `mGLView.requestRender();` is getting the values but it doesnt update the image on the screen.

```
public class OpenGL extends Fragment {


private GLSurfaceView mGLView;
private final float TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR = 180.0f / 320;
private float mPreviousX;
private float mPreviousY;
private OpenGLRenderer mRenderer;
public int height = 0;
public int width = 0;

public OpenGL() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    mGLView = new GLSurfaceView(getActivity());
    mGLView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    mRenderer = new OpenGLRenderer();
    mGLView.setRenderer(mRenderer);
    // Render the view only when there is a change in the drawing data
    mGLView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay()
            .getMetrics(displayMetrics);
     height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
     width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;


    mGLView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

                // MotionEvent reports input details from the touch screen
                // and other input controls. In this case, you are only
                // interested in events where the touch position changed.

                float x = e.getX();
                float y = e.getY();

                switch (e.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                        float dx = x - mPreviousX;
                        float dy = y - mPreviousY;

                        // reverse direction of rotation above the mid-line
                        if (y > height / 2) {
                            dx = dx * -1;
                        }

                        // reverse direction of rotation to left of the mid-line
                        if (x < width / 2) {
                            dy = dy * -1;
                        }

                        mRenderer.setAngle(
                                mRenderer.getAngle() +
                                        ((dx + dy) * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR));
                        mGLView.requestRender();
                }

                mPreviousX = x;
                mPreviousY = y;
                return true;
            }

    });

    return mGLView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mGLView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mGLView.onPause();
}
```

}

class OpenGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

```
private Triangle mRectangle;
private OpenGL mOpenGL = new OpenGL();
// mMVPMatrix is an abbreviation for "Model View Projection Matrix"
private final float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];
private float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];
float[] scratch = new float[16];
public volatile float mAngle;


public float getAngle() {
    return mAngle;
}

public void setAngle(float angle) {
    mAngle = angle;
}

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    // Set the background frame color
    //GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, mOpenGL.width, mOpenGL.height);

    float ratio = (float) mOpenGL.width / mOpenGL.height;

    // this projection matrix is applied to object coordinates
    // in the onDrawFrame() method
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);

    mRectangle = new Triangle();
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

    // Redraw background color
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Set the camera position (View matrix)
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    // Calculate the projection and view transformation
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);

    // Create a rotation for the triangle
    // long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 4000L;
    // float angle = 0.090f * ((int) time);
    Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, mAngle, 0, 0, -1.0f);

    // Combine the rotation matrix with the projection and camera view
    // Note that the mMVPMatrix factor *must be first* in order
    // for the matrix multiplication product to be correct.
    Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);

    // Draw triangle
    mRectangle.drawMatrix(scratch);
}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){

    // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

    // add the source code to the shader and compile it
    GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

    return shader;
}
```

}

class Triangle {

```
 private final String vertexShaderCodeMatrix =
         // This matrix member variable provides a hook to manipulate
         // the coordinates of the objects that use this vertex shader
         "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
                 "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                 "void main() {" +
                 // the matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position
                 // Note that the uMVPMatrix factor *must be first* in order
                 // for the matrix multiplication product to be correct.
                 "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
                 "}";

 // Use to access and set the view transformation
 private int mMVPMatrixHandle;


 private final String vertexShaderCode =
         "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                 "void main() {" +
                 "  gl_Position = vPosition;" +
                 "}";

 private final String fragmentShaderCode =
         "precision mediump float;" +
                 "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                 "void main() {" +
                 "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
                 "}";

 // number of coordinates per vertex in this array
 static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
 static float triangleCoords[] = {   // in counterclockwise order:
         0.0f,  0.622008459f, 0.0f, // top
         -0.5f, -0.311004243f, 0.0f, // bottom left
         0.5f, -0.311004243f, 0.0f  // bottom right
 };

 // Set color with red, green, blue and alpha (opacity) values
 float color[] = { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f };


 private final int mProgram;

private short[] indices = {0,1,2,0,2,3};

private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
private ShortBuffer indexBuffer;

 public Triangle() {

     // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
     ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
             // (number of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
             triangleCoords.length * 4);
     // use the device hardware's native byte order
     bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

     // create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
     vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
     // add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
     vertexBuffer.put(triangleCoords);
     // set the buffer to read the first coordinate
     vertexBuffer.position(0);

     int vertexShader = OpenGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
             vertexShaderCode);
     int fragmentShader = OpenGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
             fragmentShaderCode);

     // create empty OpenGL ES Program
     mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

     // add the vertex shader to program
     GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);

     // add the fragment shader to program
     GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader);

     // creates OpenGL ES program executables
     GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);
 }

 private int mPositionHandle;
 private int mColorHandle;

 private final int vertexCount = triangleCoords.length / COORDS_PER_VERTEX;
 private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

 public void draw() {
     // Add program to OpenGL ES environment
     GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

     // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
     mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

     // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
     GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

     // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
     GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
             GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
             vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

     // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
     mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

     // Set color for drawing the triangle
     GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

     // Draw the triangle
     GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

     // Disable vertex array
     GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
 }

 public void drawMatrix(float[] mvpMatrix) { // pass in the calculated transformation matrix


     // Add program to OpenGL ES environment
     GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

     // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
     mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

     // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
     GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

     // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
     GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
             GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
             vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

     // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
     mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

     // Set color for drawing the triangle
     GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

     // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
     mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");

     // Pass the projection and view transformation to the shader
     GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);

     // Draw the triangle
     GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

     // Disable vertex array
     GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You loaded 'vertexShaderCode' instead of 'vertexShaderCodeMatrix' in the Triangle class.